# Отображение данных в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, retrofit

Есть вот такой Json http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=M%C3%BCnchen,DE&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22 с сайта https://openweathermap.org/ используя Retrofit получаю необходимые мне данные но когда пытаюсь вывести их на экран, срабатывает через раз, иногда выводит иногда нет, при том что данные приходят каждый раз нормально. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть дело.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RestManager restManager;

private List<ModelWeather> listItems;
@BindView(R.id.recyclerview)
RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setRecyclerView();

    restManager = new RestManager();

    Call<ModelWeather> call =  restManager.getWeatherAPI().getWeather();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelWeather>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ModelWeather> call, Response<ModelWeather> response) {
            Log.d("Log", "onResponse: Server Response: " + response.toString());
            Log.d("Log", "onResponse: received information: " + response.body().toString());
            ArrayList<ListWeather> listWeathers = response.body().getListWeather();
            for(int i = 0; i < listWeathers.size(); i++){
                ModelWeather modelWeather = listWeathers.get(i);

                listItems.add(modelWeather);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ModelWeather> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Log", "onFailure: Something went wrong: " + t.getMessage() );
        }
    });
}

public void setRecyclerView(){
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(listItems);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

Адаптер:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

private List<ModelWeather> weatherList;

public RecyclerAdapter(List<ModelWeather> weatherList) {
    this.weatherList = weatherList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.weather_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ModelWeather weather = weatherList.get(position);
    holder.tempText.setText(weather.getListWeather().get(position).getMain().getTemp());
    holder.descriptionText.setText(weather.getListWeather().get(position).getWeather().get(0).getDescription());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return weatherList.size();
}}
```

Comment: `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` забыли дописать в конце onResponse

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно упустил из виду.